# Assign an interface to a struct field

Tags: go, reflection, type-conversion

Consider we have an aggregation struct of interfaces

```
type Aggregation struct {
    a InterfaceA
    b InterfaceB
    ...
    n InterfaceN
}
```

we are trying to make the following function to initialize this struct's fields more funky -- to eliminate the switch:

```
func (a *Aggregation) Register(i interface{}) *Aggregation {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case InterfaceA:
        a.a = v
    case InterfaceB:
        a.a = b
    ...
    case InterfaceN:
        a.a = v
    }
    return a
}
```

is there any way to accomplish the same functionality with reflection?

Comment: Yes, you can set struct fields with reflection. Can you show an example of the problem you are having?

Comment: @jimb I couldn't figure out how to check whenever the argument `i interface{}` implements one of the field's interfaces, but now seem to got it

Comment: BTW interfaces don't have fields - only methods. Fixed title.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working

```
func (a *Aggr) Register2(i interface{}) *Aggr {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
        f := v.Field(j)
        t := f.Type()
        if reflect.TypeOf(i).Implements(t) {
            f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(i))
            break
        }
    }
    return a
}
```

cc @jimb

Comment: It will only work if the fields of the Aggregation struct type (Aggr type in your code) are exported. Otherwise, it will panic with a message as follows: reflect.Value.Set using value obtained using unexported field.